# Problem with method "delete" of an Angular API Service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm develop an CRUD of an Clients Table, i've implemented get, post and put methods without problems, but when i try delete method and run it, navigator return an 404 error, for example:

```
delete(cliente: ClienteOrden): Observable<Response>{
    return this._http.delete<Response>(`${this.url}/${cliente.idCliente}` this.url, httpOptions)
```

delete() output: https://localhost:5001/api/Cliente/21
where 21 is cliente.idCliente

Navigator Responde: DELETE: error 404, we all to know what is it, this is, "there is'n nothing" in this url.

Web Service in Backend (.NET): OK, i did test it with swagger, result OK for CRUD operation.

Then the problem is located in Frontend, more specific, API service.

Comment: delete isn't supposed to *send* JSON. or you mean that server doesn't *return* JSON?

Answer (score 0):

i could solve this problem, with following lines:

`````
delete(cliente: ClienteOrden): Observable<Response>{

    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      body: {
        idCliente: `${cliente.idCliente}`,
        nombre: ''

      }
    }
    return this._http.delete<Response>(this.url, options)

  }
````
`````

Comment: this isn't a recommended solution as your backend is atypical. a DELETE verb generally shouldn't include a body. You probably want to fix your backend to actually use the URL instead of the body. if this is just a learning project, it's definitely in your interest to learn to do it right. If it's an actual project, you definitely want it done right.

Comment: Hi bryan60, thank for respond, you have reason but Angular Documentation allows to do so, the problem isn't in backend is in Frontend, and i' learned both ways.

Comment: the http client lets you to support older legacy systems or improperly built systems. they exist and the client doesn't want to preclude them or be overly opinionated, that doesn't mean you should do things wrong. the problem IS 100% on your backend, and whoever taught you to include a body in a delete was wrong. the REST API spec is widely available and exists for a reason.

Comment: Ok Bryan60, i going to review the Backend. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

on the Backend:

```
[HttpDelete]

        public IActionResult Delete(ClienteViewModels OModel)
        {
            Respuesta ORespuesta = new Respuesta();
            ORespuesta.Exito = 0;

            try
            {
                using (VentasRealContext db = new VentasRealContext())
                {
                    ClienteOrden OCliente = db.ClienteOrdens.Find(OModel.idCliente);
                    OCliente.Nombre = OModel.Nombre;
                    db.Remove(OCliente).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Deleted;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ORespuesta.Exito = 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                ORespuesta.Mensaje = Ex.Message;
            }

            return Ok(ORespuesta);
        }
```

I'll do following Changes:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]

        public IActionResult Delete(long id)
        {
            Respuesta ORespuesta = new Respuesta();
            ORespuesta.Exito = 0;

            try
            {
                using (VentasRealContext db = new VentasRealContext())
                {
                    ClienteOrden OCliente = db.ClienteOrdens.Find(id);
                    db.Remove(OCliente);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    ORespuesta.Exito = 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                ORespuesta.Mensaje = Ex.Message;
            }

            return Ok(ORespuesta);
        }
```

Byan60, now it works.

```
Frontend:

delete(cliente: ClienteOrden): Observable<Response>{

    
    return this._http.delete<Response>(`${this.url}/${cliente.idCliente}`, httpOptions)

  }
```

spec REST!!!! Thank you Bryan60